# Integrate remote apps RDS HTML5 WebClient in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, rds

Our company has an existing web application in ASP.NET MVC and we would like to integrate the functionality to directly (seamlessly no 2nd authentication) open a remote app in the browser using the Microsoft RDS HTML WebClient.

I have already looked around but the only things I can find is customizing the existing webclient's pages in very limited ways.

I'm hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. I have also found 3rd party RDP solutions like myrtille and guacamole.

Comment: You should put what you have looked around in your question to narrow down the question. [This link may help you in asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The only things I can find is customizing the existing webclient's pages

I have also found 3rd party RDP solutions like myrtille and guacamole.

These are not what I want.